# Just installed Fedora 18 and computer is not booting

Tags: windows-8, fedora, multi-boot, mbr, uefi

After some initial trouble, I was able to install Fedora 18, but Had to Disable Secure Boot, disable Fast Boot, and Enable CSM.

Side Note: I was reading that by Enableing CSM I was not going to be able to boot Windows 8, but the fact is that Windows 8 booted normally (before installing Fedora).

Below what I did.

Followed the normal installation process, booted Fedora DVD, when selecting the Partition Layout it complained about needing a 1MB BIOS Boot, so I created it and continued with the installation.

Now, After installing Fedora, nothing is booting, I just get the BIOS settings screen and the only boot option is the CD/DVD media.

I can boot Fedora Live CD and installed gparted. All the partitions are there, So I am sure Fedora installed correctly and I still have Windows partitions, but somehow the boot got messed up. I would need to maybe reinstall grub or something similar??

Below is a screen of gparted (using Fedora Live CD)

[gparted](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2956296/IMG_20130409_092259.JPG)

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to start all over. Booted from Fedor 18 Live Desktop, installed gparted, erased the linux partitions, then created home, root and swap partitions. Then I proceeded with the normal installation process. Now when selecting the partitions layout I followed [JA Watson](http://www.zdnet.com/how-i-installed-fedora-18-with-uefi-secure-boot_p11-7000013464/#photo) guide, which he recommended to pick the existing Windows EFI partition and mount as mount point /boot/efi. I did not have to create a BIOS Boot partition as I had originally done.

I have Fast Boot enabled and UEFI enabled as well.

Comment: You should avoid answers that depends on external links, as those can expire.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go into the firmware and disable CSM/BIOS/legacy support -- but do *not* re-enable Secure Boot. With any luck, that will at least get Windows booting. From there, you can manually install an [EFI-mode boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) Details depend on what you decide to use. One approach is:

1. Install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) from Windows, following the instructions on the rEFInd site.
2. Install the ext4fs EFI driver that comes with rEFInd. (This involves copying one file; see the rEFInd documentation.)
3. When you reboot into rEFInd, you should see one or more generic Linux icons, along with a Windows icon. Highlight one of the Linux icons and hit F2 or Insert twice. This should open a simple line editor.
4. Add `ro root=/dev/sda5` to the boot options and press Enter. Linux should boot.
5. In Linux, run the `mkrlconf.sh` script that comes with rEFInd. This will generate a configuration file that will eliminate the need to add `ro root=/dev/sda5` to your boot options every time you boot.

It's possible to do much the same thing with GRUB or ELILO, but the details differ.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...Before posting here. I disabled CSM and tried booting that way. Still nothing, went straight to BIOS Settings

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by:

- Ensuring CSM/BIOS/legacy support was disabled in the firmware.
- Using GParted to remove the bios_grub flag (in your case from sda7).

Comment: Thank you for your response. See my answer for more details.